# javascript, jQuery, Ajax Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I need some help. I'm trying to write a JQuery autocomplete script which will call a url via AJAX and get autocomplete results as user enters data into the form. However I keep getting a

> TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function

Here is my code

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

$(document).ready(function () {
   var test = ["Roanoke", "Salem", "Alexandria", "Buena Vista", "Bedford", "Bristol", 
       "Charlottesville", "Chesapeake", "Clifton Forge"];
   
   $("#city").autocomplete({
        source: test
    });
    
   $("#city").autocomplete({
        source: "city.php"
    });
   
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Style.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script/jscript.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body id = "body">
        <section><label id = "adr">Address:</label>
                    <label id = "add"><input type="text" name="address" id="address" placeholder="enter address"></label>
                    <br>
                    <input type="text" name="city" id="city" placeholder="enter city">
                    <label id = "st"><input type="text" name="state" id="state" placeholder="enter state"></label>
                    <label id = "zi"><input type="text" name="zip" id="zip" placeholder="enter zip code"></label>  
                </form>

            </div>
        </section>

    </body>
</html>
```

I ma hoping that someone will help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Autocomplete is a part of jQueryUI not jQuery. Read up about autocomplete here: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/. That website also will have links to download jquery ui.

You've included two different versions of jQuery but no jQuery UI